# PyQt5: Textbox's Not working in windows 11

Tags: python, pyqt5

I recently switched to windows 11 and decided to start a QyQt5 Project, I started to add buttons, which worked. But when I try to type in the textbox it will not display text and not type anything. The only thing it showed was that I had highlighted the textbox. Sadly there is no error or logs showing why it is behaving like this.
This is what happens:
[image: Textbox not showing text / sign of typing]

And this is the code that I have used:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(332, 121)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.Download = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Download.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 70, 75, 23))
        self.Download.setObjectName("Download")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 70, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.linkbox = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.linkbox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(23, 30, 291, 21))
        self.linkbox.setToolTipDuration(-5)
        self.linkbox.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.linkbox.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhMultiLine|QtCore.Qt.ImhNoEditMenu)
        self.linkbox.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.linkbox.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.linkbox.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
        self.linkbox.setTabChangesFocus(True)
        self.linkbox.setPlainText("")
        self.linkbox.setObjectName("linkbox")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "ChaosCapture"))
        self.Download.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Download"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Options"))
        self.linkbox.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter the download link here"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a very small height for the QPlainTextEdit, and it's completely covered by the horizontal scroll bar (which you've set as always on).

You are also *not* using [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), which is highly discouraged. For instance, the user can resize the window and make it smaller, so the widgets can become partially visible or completely hidden. Layout managers should be always preferred against predetermined geometries.

There are three things that should be done:

1. set a [layout in Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html), in your case a grid layout would be fine: right click on an empty area of the window, open the "Lay out" menu and select "Lay Out in a Grid";
2. set an arbitrary *minimum height* for the plain text edit (so that you can resize the window in designer);
3. in the *program* script, set a minimum height for the widget based on the *font metrics*;

Note that the program script ***must*** be a separate file, not the one you're showing us (the pyuic file), which must ***never*** be manually edited for any reason (read more about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html)).

The following code assumes that the pyuic file is named `ui_mainwindow.py`.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.linkbox.setMinimumHeight(
            self.fontMetrics().height() + 
            self.linkbox.frameWidth() * 2 +
            self.linkbox.document().documentMargin() * 2 + 
            self.linkbox.horizontalScrollBar().sizeHint().height()
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note: hiding the vertical scroll bar is not a very good idea. You either use a QLineEdit, or you should at least make the QPlainTextEdit a bit higher (`self.fontMetrics().height() * 2 + ...`), otherwise it would be very confusing if the user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key by mistake or pastes text with new lines.

Comment: @NaeemAhmed "do not edit" doesn't mean "do not use". Have you read the link in the answer?

Comment: @NaeemAhmed Then what is it that you don't understand?

Comment: A bad practice doesn't show warnings, but can create problems or complicate things unnecessarily. There are lots of reasons for which those files shouldn't be modified: you could decide to change the UI because you forgot something, which will force you to rebuild the file again (you could even overwrite it by mistake, so you'll lose everything you've written), then you have to merge it with the modifications you've done, and this often results in errors, maybe because of a wrong copy/paste, or because you don't remember that you modified something in the generated code.

Comment: Then, the classes in those files are simple python objects that don't allow implementation of QObject features (signals, slots, qt properties), nor overriding the methods of the QWidget classes (like event handlers), and it can't be used as a parent of other widgets since parents can only be QWidget instances. Those "form classes" are only convenience classes that should *only* be used as base for multiple inheritance (along with the QWidget class) OR as a separate instance used to "setup" the UI on the widget instance. Editing them is completely pointless and can only result in problems.